# A default varbinary(max) value for image

Tags: c#, sql-server, varbinarymax

I have a web application which has a user to insert images. I am finding a way to set a default `varbinary(MAX)` value in database `(SQL Server 2008)`. Maybe something like Facebook which has a default profile picture once you sign up. I am able to upload images to the database and display it out. I able to generate those image into a PDF file `(if the image column is NOT NULL)` else I get error decoding my image, so I need a default `varbinary(MAX)` image to represent that the column of image is not inserted. Please help me out really in need of it for my project.

Comment: Does it *have* to be a default entry in the database? Because you'll waste a lot of space that way. Why not catch it software side, where you have the default image once in a variable and use that, something like: `if (column == null || column == DBNull.Value) { column = defaultImage; }`?

Comment: you mean have a default image in my project then use this method `if (column == null || column == DBNull.Value) { column = defaultImage; }` to check if the column in null? if it null then use the default image to represent the column data?

Comment: Yes, that way you don't need to fill the database with unnecessary data. An even better way would be to have a separate image table with an ImageID and the varbinary and then reference that ImageID as a ForeignKey from other tables. So for example the first one (`ImageID = 1`) could be your default image and in the other table(s) you have a ForeignKey Field that defaults to `1`.

Answer (score 1):

If your are looking at storing files/images I would recomend looking at [FILESTREAM Overview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

> Much of the data that is created every day is unstructured data, such
>   as text documents, images, and videos. This unstructured data is often
>   stored outside the database, separate from its structured data. This
>   separation can cause data management complexities. Or, if the data is
>   associated with structured storage, the file streaming capabilities
>   and performance can be limited.
>
> FILESTREAM integrates the SQL Server Database Engine with an NTFS file
>   system by storing varbinary(max) binary large object (BLOB) data as
>   files on the file system. Transact-SQL statements can insert, update,
>   query, search, and back up FILESTREAM data. Win32 file system
>   interfaces provide streaming access to the data.
>
> FILESTREAM uses the NT system cache for caching file data. This helps
>   reduce any effect that FILESTREAM data might have on Database Engine
>   performance. The SQL Server buffer pool is not used; therefore, this
>   memory is available for query processing.

Comment: Don't really understand what it trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert an image, or any kind of file, into a SQL row using code like this:

```
/*get blob from file, store in variable*/
declare @blob as varbinary(max)
set @blob = (
    Select BulkColumn from Openrowset
    ( Bulk 'c:\temp\MyImage.jpg', Single_Blob) as tt)

/* insert blob into row */
insert into dbo.MyImageTable (Name, Blob) 
values('SomeName',@blob)
```

Using this, you can store a single default image on a table then just link it to the rows that need a default image using a simple join like this:

```
 select * from MyData join MyImageTable on MyImageTable.Name='SomeName'
```